# Magento 2 : Get total spent by customer

Tags: magento2, orders, customer

Is their any way we can get total amount that has been spend by customer in magento
2 ?

Comment: Total amount for all orders that have been placed by customer?

Comment: yes, Total Spent on order by customer.

Comment: I meant to ask that for particular order or all orders which have been placed by customer?

Comment: Thanks for the response.
All orders total placed by customer.

Comment: Thanks. Do you need it for particular customer or for all customers?

Comment: for a single customer

Comment: Someone has posted answer for you and this is a correct answer.

Comment: I am not sure, i have checked & it returns 0.

Comment: Will provide you an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load the order collection for example by customer email, then loop through the orders totalling the value:

```
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory
    ) {
       $this->orderCollectionFactory = $orderCollectionFactory;
    }

    public function test()
    {
        
        $customerEmail="testcustomer@mycoolshop.com";
        $total=0;
        $orders = $this->orderCollectionFactory->create()
            ->addAttributeToFilter('customer_email', $customerEmail);
        foreach ($orders as $order) {
            echo "Order# {$order->getIncrementId()} - Creation Date: {$order->getCreatedAt()} - Value: {$order->getGrandTotal()}". PHP_EOL;
            $total=$total+$order->getGrandTotal();
        }
        echo "Total for customer:".$total.PHP_EOL;


    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, let me check

Comment: I am getting 0 only.

Comment: are you using a valid email address for a customer that has placed orders?

Comment: Yes valid email address, i have echo count($orders); that returns 4, it seems like issue is with $order->getGrandTotal()

Comment: changing getGrandTotal to getTotal works.

Comment: If the answer helped you to accomplish some cool stuff, please accept it so that we can share the love...

Comment: just one question, how can i add up totals in loop >?

Comment: In the example the total is being added to the $total variable in a foreach loop.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120451/discussion-between-devhs-and-paj).

Answer (score 1):

Please add below code in any root file. Please create custom.php file in root of magento folder and check your output.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$storeManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$OrderFactory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory');
$orderCollection = $OrderFactory->create()->addFieldToSelect(array('*'));
$orderCollection->addAttributeToFilter('customer_email', 'test@zealousweb.com');

$total = 0;
foreach($orderCollection as $orderData)
{
     $total = $total + $orderData->getGrandTotal();
}   

echo $total;
die();
```

Comment: If this script is helpful for you then please approve and upvote this. Many thanks!

Comment: You mean that the above file can  be place outside the app folder?